# Django 1.8 migration strange behaviour

Tags: python, django, migration

I am trying to modify an existing `School` app which has sub-apps like `students, class, scores etc` using django 1.8.

My class model:

```
class Class(Object):
    student = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='school_student')
    section = models.CharField()
    roll = models.IntegerField()
```

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations class`, I am getting a message `No changes detected in app 'class'`.

But when I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, the changes are detected and the migration files are created under the `school directory` but not in the `class directory`.

But when to the above model if I add a `meta` class.

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('student', 'roll')
```

And now if I run `python manage.py makemigrations class`, the changes are detected and the migration files are created under the `class directory`.

Can someone tell me why such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **A model is not a subapp.**

If that's clear: IIRC, Django 1.8 requires a `class Meta` to know which app a model belongs to.

If you only have an additional model, you need `class Meta` to specify the app_label.

If you have a real subapp (i.e. an app within a app), you also need to add it to settings.INSTALLED_APPS for their migrations to work properly.